# What is the expression you make trying not to smile?

Tags: creative-writing, terminology

I have been trying to see if there is an expression for this for a while now. You know when you're about to laugh or smile at something, but that would be inappropriate or embarrassing, so you force a frown but your eyes are still smiling? Is there an expression for this?

Comment: My eyes don't smile without my face.  My face sometimes smiles without my eyes, but not vice versa.  When I'm stifling a laugh or a grin, that either comes off as a blank expression, which is stoic, or comes off as a grimace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a single iconic word. I would say "suppressing X"; for example Suppressing the urge to laugh, or suppressing a grin, etc.

If you see it on someone else, you can tell because their is a smile around their eyes but their lips are compressed by the force they exert to hold in a grin or laugh.

So "holding in a grin".

There is nothing wrong with using a phrase or description. In general, when writing fiction, it is better to use a visual description employing commonly used words, than to use an obscure word or phrase that most of your audience won't understand. I think we are trying to aid the reader's imagination, not expand their vocabulary.

Perhaps if you are certain there IS a commonly understood word and you're having a brain glitch on it, go looking. Otherwise, just paint the picture with a handful of words.

Comment: An insightful answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about *keep a straight face*?

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/dictionary/english/keep-a-straight-face

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep-a-straight-face

Or maybe you could adapt some adjectives such as *straight-faced*, *poker-faced*, *deadpan*?